# home partition not mounted during system startup

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

I tried to install another OS alongside with the current Ubuntu 16.04, but at the end of the installation process when grub should be installed a fatal error occurred. Since then, I cannot boot to my OS any longer. "Welcome to emergency mode" is what I see instead of login screen. I found that `/home` partition isn't mounted. To mount it I do `mount -a` in this "emergency mode" then press `Ctrl + D` and then the OS is loading normally. `mount /etc/sda9 /home && systemctl default` also works fine.

Here is my `fstab`:

```
# / was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=43c8292e-dfce-4191-9040-8797667be0e3 /      ext4   errors=remount-ro 0  1
# /boot was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=2b80fd17-a9d5-4c80-8e6e-d917f4e02cc0 /boot  ext2   defaults  0     2
# /home was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=0873df66-f7fe-416c-bebf-eec4e26f11e7 /home  ext4   defaults  0     2
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=52728841-4b38-416b-888c-9742e98a2943 none   swap    sw     0       0
```

What can I do to get it back to work?

Comment: And what exactly does this `mount /etc/sda9  /home` do? Please run `fsck /dev/sda9` when in emergency!

Comment: I would `fsck` as George suggested; then check the UUID for your $HOME is correct, ie. compare the output of `lsblk` (list block devices) & the UUID for /dev/sda9 matches the UUID in your `/etc/fstab` (file-system table)

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I guess it mounts my home partition at `/home`. As was suggested on another resource, I ran `sudo fsck -vf /dev/sda9`, it found and fixed some errors. Afterwards OS started normally. It seems like the partition somehow was corrupted by the installer.

Comment: Please answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: I was having exactly same problem and `fsck /dev/sda4` fixed it for me. Thanks a lot  @GeorgeUdosen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was with the partition itself. I used `fsck -vf /dev/sda9` (sda9 was the home partition, I knew it from `/etc/fstab` file). This command found and fixed some errors and OS was able to start normally again. Thank everybody for help!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the **root partition is not mounted by default**.
Where one has to mount manually through the **shell root prompt** of advance boot options using the command by pressing `ctrl+alt+f3 | f4 | f5` while booting.

1. perform a thorough `fsck` on all partitions before mounting. `lsblk` will show you all the partition names.
2. `fsck /dev/{partition-name}`
3. remount all the partitions with read-write access
   `mount -n -0 remount, rw /`
4. type `exit` and **resume** your boot without **rebooting**
5. you should be able to login by now.

For a **permanent solution**, one has to find the **root partition** 
 6. using command `lsblk`
   or manually finding from the directory /dev/your-root-partition. you can cat /etc/fstab to find the root partition
It will say

```
# / was on /dev/{your-partition-name} during installation
```

7. edit the `fstab` in the `/etc/fstab`
   to mount the root partition while booting automatically with **rw access** and add

   `/dev/{your-boot-directory} / ext3 rw 0 1`
8. **save the file** and update your grub

   `sudo update-grub`
9. `reboot` now it should login as normal.

**Credits:**

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=118114

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264598/system-will-not-boot-because-boot-partition-is-missing

https://geek-university.com/linux/etc-fstab-file/

https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount